# Transistor and diode on induction cookware

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism

Will a 1 kW induction cook top damage a transistor which is kept on its surface? If yes,  what is the mechanism? Is it electromagnetic induction?

Answer (score 1):

An induction heater creates an oscillating magnetic field near the coil.

The "mechanism" to damage an electronic component is that eddy currents are induced in the metal parts of the component.  These eddy currents heat up the part until something breaks.

If the part breaks, yes, it will be due to magnetic induction.